# Problems with html email spacing

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email, outlook-2013

I'm trying to stop this custom footer from showing spacing between tables! It works great if I send it from outlook to outlook (2013), but in any other client such as yahoo mail, hotmail etc the spacing gets completely messed up.  I've tried adding everything I can think of, but I'm not getting anywhere!

Here's what I have so far:

```
<style>
table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding:0;

}

th, td 
{ 
padding: 0px; 
vertical-align: top;
}

td {
vertical-align:text-top;
}

</style>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;padding: 0; width:746px;">
    <tr>
        <td width="34" height="93" border="0" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_01.jpg" width="34" height="93" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="11" height="93" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_02.jpg" width="11" height="93" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="183" height="93" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_03.jpg" width="183" height="93" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td colspan="7" width="518" height="93" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_04.jpg" width="518" height="93" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" width="228" height="137" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_05.jpg" width="228" height="137" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td colspan="7" width="518" height="89" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_06.jpg" width="518" height="89" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="235" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_07.jpg" width="235" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="53" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_08.jpg" width="53" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="46" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_09.jpg" width="46" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="37" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_10.jpg" width="37" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="44" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_11.jpg" width="44" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="42" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_12.jpg" width="42" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
        <td width="61" height="48" style="padding: 0px;vertical-align: top;">
            <img src="http://www.paperplanes.io/signature/images/signature_13.jpg" width="61" height="48" alt="" style="display: block;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Gaps between what tables? You only have one...

Comment: It's when it's sent from outlook 2013 to a client like yahoo or gmail.  Outlook 2013 tends to put all sorts of rubbish in there.

Comment: If i add this into Outlook 2013, it breaks completely if it's sent to Gmail, Yahoo etc. But to outlook it works fine!

I've created the HTM file and added it to the signatures area.